# Find the data set for boundary/edge of ListPlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, dataset

I have a   data set, say,  {$x_i, y_i$}. After plotting which looks like the following

[image]

How can I get the data set for the boundary from this. Here is the link for my [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qza4t8qukxtrz3w/xy.dat?dl=0)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83593/is-there-an-efficient-algorithm-to-generate-a-2d-concave-hull) should be relevant.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark edited

Comment: Please post the data set.

Comment: @cvgmt posted it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Also use `NonConvexHullMesh`.

```
pts = Import["xy.dat"];
reg = ResourceFunction["NonConvexHullMesh"][pts, .001];
bdreg = RegionBoundary[reg];
dist = RegionDistance[bdreg];
bdpts = Select[pts, dist[#] == 0 &];
Graphics[{{Green, bdreg}, {Opacity[.2], Yellow, reg}, {Red, 
   Point[bdpts]}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

`im` is the image.

```
pts = -Cross /@ DeleteDuplicates[Round[Position[ImageData[im, "Byte"], {25, 204, 255, 255}], 2]];
```

If you plot the points as huge disks, you can only see the circular boundary of those disks that have a center point on the boundary of the region. In the interior nearby disks cover it.

To check which disks are covered, I used the 10 nearest points to each point, and checked which disks were covered at some random but large radius.

```
sets = N[Nearest[pts, pts, {∞, 10}]];
R = 50.;

cover = If[# < #2, {{#, #2}}, {{#, π}, {-π, #2}}] & @@
    ArcTan @@ With[{ca = #2[[1]] - #[[1]], db = #2[[2]] - #[[2]]},
      {{ca, ca}, {db, db}} + {{db, -db}, {-ca, ca}} Sqrt[4. #3 #3/(ca ca + db db) - 1.]] &;
```

`cover[pt1, pt2, r]` gives 1 or 2 intervals within -pi to pi, which tell which what part of the circle with center `pt1` is covered by a disk with center `pt2` given radius `r`.

Those not fully covered are used:

```
which = Table[Interval[{-π, π}] === Interval @@ Catenate[cover[sets[[i, 1]], #, R] & /@ Rest[sets[[i]]]], {i, Length[sets]}];
boundaryPts = Pick[pts, which, False];

Show[ListLinePlot[boundaryPts[[Last[FindShortestTour[boundaryPts]]]]],
     ListPlot[pts, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Little different, the parameters need adjusting

A rough attempt edge detect vertically and horizontally

Using Coolwater's really nice use of `ShortestPath` to plot

[image]

```
v = Table[
   Position[xy[[All, 1]], #] & /@ 
    MinMax[Select[xy, i + 0.001 > #[[2]] > i &][[All, 1]]], {i, 0.01, 
    0.026, 0.001}] // Flatten
h = Table[
   Position[xy[[All, 2]], #] & /@ 
    MinMax[Select[xy, j + 0.0001 > #[[1]] > j &][[All, 2]]], {j, 
    0.03255, 0.03365, 0.0001}] // Flatten
Join[v, h]
xy[[#]] & /@ %

Show[ListPlot[{xy, %}, PlotStyle -> {Black
    , Red}], ListLinePlot[%[[Last[FindShortestTour[%]]]]]]
```